# Custom Lock Behavior: Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tree

Is there a way to change the lock.acquire() behavior in such a way that it only attempts to fetch the lock and does something else if it has been locked by another process?

Current code: (If the thread encounters a tree node that is locked it is supposed to restart the query from the parent)

```
if current.parent.lock.locked():           ...this current behavior is not thread safe
    return _get_node(data, current.parent)
else:
    current.parent.lock.acquire()
    current.lock.acquire()
    left.lock.acquire()                    ...or... right.lock.acquire()
```

I have found [this](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) website explaining some things, but this seems to not be a thing people do very often as finding more relevant information was a no no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Python docs] the `acquire` method has a `blocking` argument. When this is set to `False` the request is non-blocking and returns `True` when successful (you now have acquired the lock)  or `False` when the lock was already acquired by someone else and not yet released.

The resulting code is:

```
if lock.acquire(False):
    # code if lock is acquired
else:
    # code if lock was already acquired by someone else
```

Comment: i thought it meant that the thread holding the lock would be unable to block and be kicked off immediately. huray for false assumptions. Thank you very much good sir +1